# Why exactly isn't this solve valid

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Assume $x^2+x+1=0$ --①

Thus   $x+1=-x^2$ --②

Since $x=0$ is not a root of ①, thus divide both side of ① by x to get

$x+1+\frac{1}{x}=0$,

Since ②, we have 
$-x^2+\frac {1}{x}=0$

Thus $x^3=1$ and thus $x=1$.

I know that the other two complex roots of $x^3$ is root for the original equation, and I know there's something wrong with the dividing part, but what exact principle did it break?

Comment: You have simply found a root of a new equation which is not a root of the original one. If x - 1 = 0 then $x^2 = 1$ which has a root x = -1, as another example.

Comment: at which exact step did the addition root was introduced? That's what I failed to see.

Comment: The answer below is clear. For my example I would be multiplying by (x + 1) which is 0 when x = -1.

Answer (score 6):

The overall effect of your manipulations (dividing by $x$, subtracting, and multiplying by $x$) is to say $$x^2+x+1=0 \\ \implies (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0 \\ \implies x^3-1=0  \\ \implies x^3=1$$  and there is nothing wrong with those as one-way implications.

That final equation gives has three complex roots, one of which is $x=1$.  But that one is in fact not a root to the first equation.  This spurious solution was introduced by the multiplication by $(x-1)$, which is $0$ when $x=1$.